# How to get unique id for multiple Geofence object on callback

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add 5 geofancy circle & want to get call back when user enter & exit, I set each geofancy request I'd but unable to get it on callback method.

Your answer is very helpful .

Comment: You should be able to get the `Geofence` from the `GeofenceEvents` from the intent.  From the `Geofence` you can get its `requestId`.  Post your callback/intent processing to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not clear.
But as the question is about unique Id's you can do it by using time stamp i.e.

1st.

```
id = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

Use this as id for whatever your object is.

2nd.

You can use :

```
id = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

use this id for more unique ids.

Comment: @abdul rahaman. Thanks for your answer, but I have already added unique I'd, but want to get I'd in callback method , call back method call when user enter or exit.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet? I don't know what are you doing in your code or how it is working.